# Using GooglePay with Paypal Gateway

Tags: android, paypal, gateway, google-pay

I'm integrating Google pay into my app. The problem is that I did not find Paypal on the [supported gateway list](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/). It seems impossible, does Paypal gateway have a different name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of the mobile division of Paypal is Braintree.

> Braintree, a division of PayPal, is a company based in Chicago that
>   specializes in mobile and web payment systems for e-commerce companies
>   that was acquired by PayPal on September 26, 2013 - WIKIPEDIA